# Can a Chrome Extension content script trigger a keyboard event received by the origin site?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

The following code words if run in the console itself:

```
    var $inputbox = $('input#inputfield');
    var SPACE_KEYCODE = 32;
    var space_down = $.Event( 'keyup', { which: SPACE_KEYCODE } );
    $inputbox.trigger(space_down)
```

I can see the event being triggered and the page responding.

However when running the same code in a content script via a Chrome extension, it fails silently. Logging the results of '$inputbox.trigger(space_down)' shows it correctly returning the element.

The intention here is to have the existing page JS respond to the keyboard event from the extension. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't been able to find documentation about whether events are distinct between the content script JS 'world' and the origin site's world, I made the following in the content script to load some JS into window.location, making it run in the content of the origin site.

```
// In order to send keyboard events, we'll need to send them from the page's JS
var load_into_page_context = function(file) {
    var file_url = chrome.extension.getURL(file);
    $.get(file_url, function(script_contents) {
        window.location = 'javascript:'+script_contents
    })

}

    load_into_page_context("injectme.js");
```

This will load injectme.js (bundled with the extension) into the window.location, and make the generated keyboard events activate the origin site's event handlers.

Comment: Just thought Id point out theres quite a few ways to inject code into the page.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906083/chrome-extension-invoke-page-script-by-injection  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script and Ive seen a few other variations on it all